# Connect to a 32-bit Access database from 64-bit .NET program

Tags: .net, vb.net, com, office-interop

I'm working on a VB .NET interface, that I just realized will need to be run as a 64-bit program because of one of the COM references I'm using (machine vision software) will only work in 64-bit, so compiling as x86 is out completely. I'm also linking this GUI to a simple user login that checks a user name and password against an Access database when my program launches.

Office 2007 is what is installed on the machine currently, which is of course 32-bit. This seems to create a problem, as my now 64-bit program can no longer communicate to the database. I can go buy a version of Office that is 64-bit, but is there any way around this?

I've been trying to do research, but couldn't find anything relating to accessing 32-bit databases from 64-bit interfaces that didn't recommend just compiling as x86 (which I can no longer do). I have the program set up for "Any CPU".

Below is the code running when the user tries to log in. The application throws an exception when `conn.Open()` is executed. This code previously worked great when it was compiled for x86.

```
If UsernameTextBox.Text = "" Or PasswordTextBox.Text = "" Then
     MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields.", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
Else
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LoginDatabase.accdb"

    Try

        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE username='" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "' AND password = '" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "'"
        Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)

        sqlCom.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()

        Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

        If sqlRead.Read() Then

            Me.Hide()
            LoginCancel = False

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Username and Password do not match.", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            PasswordTextBox.Text = ""
            UsernameTextBox.Text = ""

            UsernameTextBox.Focus()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to Database.", "Database Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

End If
```

Comment: As far as I know you need Office 64 bit. (or no office at all and install the ACE drivers for 64bit) However I have many doubts that this code worked previously. Password is a reserved keyword. You should get a syntax error in that query

Comment: Just go [here, to Microsoft's Website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) and download the 64-bit version of the Access Database engine.

Comment: Thanks all, I'll try uninstalling office and installing the Access Database Engine. Worth a shot before buying it since Office doesn't really need to be on this machine.

Answer (score 3):

A 64-bit process cannot load a 32-bit DLL. This is a hard rule. So there is no way for your program to load the Access DLL.

Instead you could write a 32-bit stub program which loads the Access DLL. And then your 64-bit program can communicate with the stub using some sort of inter process communication.

Comment: Is there anything in nuget which would do the IPC for me?

Comment: Create a COM component to wrap the Access DLL. I was able to access 32-bit COM components from a 64-bit VB.NET process.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling office and installing the 64-bit Access Database Engine worked perfectly! No changes need to existing code, worked right out of the gate. Thanks for the link Icemanind.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Except for the bit where you've uninstalled Office of course :(